# Error when running a DQN pygame script in Google Colab

Tags: python, pygame, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

When I am running a DQN script using Pygame on Google Colab it is throwing error -

> pygame.error: No available video device

I am trying to run this GitHub repo on Google Colab. [pong_neural_network_live](https://github.com/llSourcell/pong_neural_network_live)

Installed the Pygame using following code-

```
import os
!git clone https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment.git
os.chdir('PyGame-Learning-Environment')
!pip install -e .
!pip install pygame
os.chdir('/content')
```

On trying to initialize and run the following code it

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.list_modes()
```

I get

> error: video system not initialized

PS: I also enabled third party cookies in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colab is run in the cloud. It cannot send display to a window on your computer. So, you cannot use Pygame. Or you need some clever hacking like VNC.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to run pygame in Colab with some limitations.

Fool the system to think there is a video device
Capture the pygame screen and copy it to another interface compatible with Colab like OpenCV or matplotlib
Use output library to clear the cell.
Not the most elegant way, but it gets it done.

Take a look at this notebook I created: (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xtiBrGeRHmXY3KSOixkZBf_rJIgBImJu?usp=sharing)

Please notice there are limitations:

Can't read inputs from keyboard or mouse
Can't play audios
In my case I was interested to use pygame for animation purposes so I wasn't too fuzzed about it.

Comment: Thanks. That's a smart way to do it. Though there are limitations and will not be a full fledged solution anyway.